# Is there a way to extend DATA URI size limit on chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, pdf-generation, data-uri

Good day,

I have made a system that renders large amount of data into pdf file... the file sizes up to 30mb or more so if I use `open(dataUri)` the pdf is not rendered on the opened window, for now I am forcing the use to download the file before they open it.. But the problem with this is that files are being duplicated over and over again every time they click the download button.. The solution I have in mind is that to extend data uri limit on the browser (specifically chrome) since I am deploying the system locally (for now).

any suggestion are very much appreciated.. Thanks!!